# Adding a field with a value to a document returned by mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to add a `timestamp` field to each document returned by `mongo` using Python. Following is the snippet I'm using to do this but I am getting an error. Can someone help achieving this?

```
def get_dbstats(self, client):
    dbs = client.database_names()
    for db in dbs:
        stats = client[db].command('dbstats')
        print stats
        print (datetime.datetime.now())
        stats[0]['created_time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Output:

```
{u'storageSize': 90112.0, u'ok': 1.0, u'avgObjSize': 293.0, u'db': u'admin', u'indexes': 5, u'objects': 13, u'collections': 3, u'numExtents': 0, u'dataSize': 3809.0, u'indexSize': 163840.0}
2017-04-19 17:05:26.711000
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/Python01/script01.py", line 28, in <module>
    obj.get_dbstats(client)
  File "H:/Python01/script01.py", line 22, in get_dbstats
    stats[0]['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now()
KeyError: 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stats` is not a `list`, it is a `dict`.

```
stats = {   
    u'storageSize': 90112.0, 
    u'ok': 1.0, 
    u'avgObjSize': 293.0, 
    u'db': u'admin', 
    u'indexes': 5, 
    u'objects': 13, 
    u'collections': 3, 
    u'numExtents': 0, 
    u'dataSize': 3809.0, 
    u'indexSize': 163840.0
}
```

Set the timestamp field directly with:

```
stats['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: thank you Stephen. it works but when i print it shows as below, where all the fields names are started with 'u' but not to the field(log_date) i have added with datetime. Also, can you please let me know why all other fields are starting with 'u' ?
{u'storageSize': 90112.0, u'ok': 1.0, u'avgObjSize': 293.0, 'log_date': '2017-04-19 17:30:01.874000', u'db': u'admin', u'indexes': 5, u'objects': 13, u'collections': 3, u'numExtents': 0, u'dataSize': 3809.0, u'indexSize': 163840.0}

Comment: The little `u` means those strings are unicode.  If you put a `u` in front of `'timestamp'` it will then match.

Comment: oh got it ... is there a way I can convert entire dictionary to a Jason document? I have to insert this to a different collection in mongo by adding log_date field.